# What happened to (or where is) the "Accept Rate"?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

When I first discovered GIS SE two years ago, there was a statistic attached to users showing the percentage of questions that they had accepted an answer -- and even criticism lobbed at those with low rates. Am I missing something? Was there a discussion about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (for GIS-SE)

http://data.stackexchange.com/gismeta/query/69760/accept-rate-comment-with-comment-text

```
SELECT PostID [Post Link], CreationDate, UserId, Score, Text
FROM Comments
WHERE Text like '%accept rate%'
ORDER BY CreationDate Desc
```